# Vuetify : 2 rows in a card

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I tried to create new row to place my table component there, and I want it to take the entire row

I've tried

```
<v-col cols="12">
    <Table />
</v-col>
```

It goes to the right

[image]

I'm trying to have 2 rows in a card

- first row (icon) + title & subtitle
- second row table

[image]

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid class="my-5">
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
                <v-card elevation="2" class="d-flex">
                    <!-- Icon -->
                    <v-col cols="1">
                        <v-card-title>
                            <v-btn text color="black">
                                <v-icon left x-large>{{ icon }}</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-card-title>
                    </v-col>

                    <!-- Title & Subtitle -->
                    <v-col cols="11">
                        <v-card-title>
                            {{ title }}
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-card-subtitle style="color: #757575"> {{ subtitle }} </v-card-subtitle>

                        <Table />
                    </v-col>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: I think you need to add another ``<v-container>`` inside your card components for it to adjust the ``<v-row>`` and ``<v-col>`` correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using `<v-card-text>`and `<v-card-title>`instead of rows and cols ?

Comment: @Mael I tried that it works. I'm missing <v-container>

Comment: @RenaudC5 I'm very new to Vuetify, I've tried that and it places all over the place, if you know any good sample, please point me to it.. I would love to give it a shot.

Comment: You rarely need multiple v-containers.

Comment: The `d-flex` class on the `v-card` is going to mess up the v-card-title and v-card-text positioning and put them on the same row unless you specify flex direction column. You don't need it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The vuetify component v-card defines several zones:

```
<v-card>
  <v-card-title></v-card-title>
  <v-card-subtitle></v-card-subtitle>
  <v-card-text></v-card-text> <!-- this is the body of the card, where you should insert your table -->
  <v-card-actions></v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

Here you have your sample from this concept: https://codepen.io/jssDev-/pen/YzrVZjJ

Comment: It should be `v-card-text` not `v-text`

Comment: You're right. Edited

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9SQ02v9.png

Your icon, and tile/subtitle so spreadout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either create a grid inside each the card's children and use offset (example below) or create a grid inside the v-card and nest the card children in the second column that has width col-11 (not recommended as it goes outside the recommended card and card children nesting mentioned by @jssDev in the other answer).

```html
<v-card elevation="2">
  <v-card-title>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="col-1">
        <v-btn text>
          <v-icon left x-large>
            {{ icon }}
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="col-11 text-start">
        {{ title }}
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card-title>

  <v-card-subtitle>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="offset-1 col-11 text-start">
        {{ subtitle }}
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card-subtitle>

  <v-card-text>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="offset-1 col-11 text-start">
        <v-data-table :headers="[]" :items="[]" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

Comment: You snippet is not showing correct data

https://i.imgur.com/NIQGOay.png

Comment: The snippets don't have Vuetify so card title and text are meaningless when running the snippet. It should work if you paste the code into your project codebase.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is your comprehension of the [grid system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) in vuetify.

A good practice is to always put a col inside a row.

Also, vuetify has it's own way of composing a card :

A `v-card` is composed of 4 parts (which can be instanced any times each) :

- `v-card-actions` (components contaning all your action buttons (save, exit, etc.))
- `v-card-subtitle` (subtitle of the card)
- `v-card-text` (any text that composed the card)
- `v-card-title` (title of the card)

For your example, you can use the `v-card-text` to put your table. it will automatically be considred as a row containing 12 cols.

Here is an exemple of how to solve your problem

```js
<template>
  <v-card elevation="2">
      <v-card-title>
        <!-- first row of the card --> 
        <v-row>
          <!-- first col of the row (1/12)  -->
          <v-col cols="1">
            <v-btn text color="black">
              <v-icon left x-large>mdi-link</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <!-- second col of the row (11/12)  -->
          <v-col cols="11">
            Title of the card
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

      </v-card-title>

    <!-- Title & Subtitle -->
      <v-card-subtitle style="color: #757575">
        <!-- second row of the card  -->
        <v-row class="justify-end">
          <!--   col inside the row 11/12 located at the end of the row with the flex class justify-end -->
          <v-col cols="11">
            Subtitle of the vcard
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-card-subtitle>

      <v-card-text>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          :items-per-page="5"
          class="elevation-1"
        ></v-data-table>
      </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Hello",
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```